# IgnitedDatatables Server-side Column Filtering

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter, datatables

Recently I've got a problem using datatables and ignited-datatables library.

I used datatables ver. 1.10.4 and IgnitedDatatables ver. 2.0

It seems that I can't do the individual column filtering like mentioned on this link :
https://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter.html

Since every time I do the "keyup", tables reloaded, but the filter criteria is not bound into the data. Anyway by using chrome debugging tools, I know that string for searching has been sent into server : "columns[2][search][value]: some_string", but somehow the server can't process this string.

Here is my javascript code :

```
table = $('#data_table').DataTable( {
    'filter': true,
    'processing': true,
    'serverSide': true,
    'ajax': {
        'url' : '<?=site_url()?>/technician/get_data',
        'type' : 'POST',
        'data' : lar_data
    },
    'columns':[
        {'data' : 'opt_edit', 'sortable' : false,'searchable' : false},
        {'data' : 'opt_detail', 'sortable' : false, 'searchable' : false},
        {'data' : 'TechnicianName'},
        {'data' : 'TechnicianAddress'},
        {'data' : 'TechnicianMobileNumber'},
        {'data' : 'opt_delete', 'sortable' : false, 'searchable' : false}
    ],
    'order' : [[2, 'asc']]
} );

table.columns().eq( 0 ).each( function ( colIdx ) {
    $( 'input', table.column( colIdx ).footer() ).on( 'keyup', function () {
        table
            .columns( colIdx )
            .search( this.value )
            .draw();            
    } );
} );
```

The model :

```
function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->library('Datatables');
}

function get($filter)
{
    $this->datatables->select('
        TechnicianName,
        TechnicianAddress,
        TechnicianMobileNumber
    ');
    $this->datatables->add_column(
        'opt_edit',
        '<a href="#">Edit</a>'
    );
    $this->datatables->add_column(
        'opt_detail',
        '<a href="#">Detail</a>'
    );
    $this->datatables->add_column(
        'opt_delete',
        '<a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>'
    );
    $this->datatables->from('ms_technician');
    $this->datatables->where($filter);

    return $this->datatables->generate();
}
```

View :

```
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table id="data_table" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th width="1px">&nbsp;</th>
                <th width="1px">&nbsp;</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Address</th>
                <th>Mobile Phone</th>
                <th width="1px">&nbsp;</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th width="1px">&nbsp;</th>
                <th width="1px">&nbsp;</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Address</th>
                <th>Mobile Phone</th>
                <th width="1px">&nbsp;</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
        <tbody></tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Can anybody help me with this problem?
Really appreciate your help...